# Create a new CSV File?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I'm looking to create a new .csv file using python and then write to the file after that. I couldn't find a command to create a new file using the CSV library. I thought something like

```
NewFile = csv.creatfile(PATH)
```

might exist but I couldn't find something like that.

Thank you in advance! Happy to answer any questions you may have!

Comment: What don't you understand about [the example in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.writer)?

Comment: You have read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/index.html), right?

Comment: @martineau Yes I have!

Comment: @Evert I do understand the example. Writing to a file is not my issue, creating a new file is.

Comment: Which is exactly what `open('eggs.csv', 'wb')` in the example does. File creation is also [in the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

Comment: [_Reading and Writing Files_](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) is also covered in the Python 2 documentation. While you can create file objects with the built-in [`file()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#file) function, as explained in the docs, but it's preferable to use [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open). This anomaly is probably just a legacy left-over from non-object-oriented languages.

Comment: Thanks for the help @martineau!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `csv` module doesn't handle file creation; Python handles file creation as a [builtin function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) called `open` -- once you have a file handle created using `open`, you can use it with `csv.writer` or `csv.DictWriter`to write data to the file.